# Herokus strapi instanced data wipe

Tags: strapi, heroku-postgres

I have created a Heroku Postgres db for my Strapi backend. The issue I have that any data stored in the db seems to be wiped out after 24hrs.
After 24hrs I have to connect to my db with new credentials, the data structure is intact, but the data itself is not persistent.

I have other strapi instances with v3 running on Heroku without this issue.

The current app is running on Strapiv4.02. Node v16.13.0. NPM v8.2.0.

What might the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

In config vars, we have to set NODE_ENV to production.